# Rest heart without authentication

Tags: restheart

I'm using Rest Heart and I want to:

1) Disable authentication of Rest Heart. I don't want to provide any credential like admin:changeit when doing crud operations.
2) Disable authentication of Rest Heart with Mongo because my Mongo doesn't have authentication enabled (and I don't want to enable it)

I think that that can be done editing yml file, but its not clear to me even reading the documentation.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable security in RESTHeart you just comment out the following lines in restheart.yml configuration file

```
#idm:
#  implementation-class: org.restheart.security.impl.SimpleFileIdentityManager
#  conf-file: {{{idm.conf-file}}}

#access-manager:
#  implementation-class: org.restheart.security.impl.SimpleAccessManager
#  conf-file: {{{access-manager.conf-file}}}
```

The credentials of MongoDb are specified in the mongo-uri, for instance:

```
mongo-uri: mongodb://user:secret@127.0.0.1/?authSource=authdb
```

If you want to run MongoDb without security just set the following:

```
mongo-uri: mongodb://127.0.0.1/
```

Comment: I would like to add that, at least in docker version, mongo-uri property can be found in config.properties file (not in restheart.yml)

Answer (score 1):

As an update to this topic, the latest major release of RESTHeart, which is v4 and was published in June 2019, moved the security layer into another component.

So now if you run the plain RESTHeart v4 you don't have any authentication mechanism, so nothing to disable at all.

> RESTHeart v3 has been growing over the last 5 years featuring a REST
>   API for MongoDB and a strong security layer. The code got complex to
>   update and maintain, so that RESTHeart Platform v4 is now split in
>   modules clued together in a micro-service architecture.
>
> This resulted in two projects that do one thing and do it well. Each
>   of them can also be reused alone in different architectures.
>
> The two micro-services are:
>
> - [restheart-core](https://github.com/SoftInstigate/restheart) handles the REST API;
> - [restheart-security](https://github.com/SoftInstigate/restheart-security) is responsible of enforcing the security policy acting as a reverse proxy for restheart-core.

You can read [here](https://restheart.org/docs/upgrade-to-v4/) for more.